# Import aborted while processing batch 0 Data Extension Import Issue

Tags: dataextensions, error-messages, import, data-import

Import aborted while processing Batch 0 in DsvFileSourceReader

I'm getting this issue when importing a data extension, using a nickname as the Primary Key, what is the potential issue here? Have 25 fields, 2 of which are not mapped, all fields are nullable except the primary key and email of which all entries have these.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the .csv file, there were fields that were missing that were required as well as bad formatting for the required fields.